# Schedule Batch Apex to run batch one after another in hours gap

Tags: apex, integration, schedulebatch

I have a scenario where we are having a batch apex(batch size 1000) to be schedule to run daily which perform API callouts. I need to split batches to run after every one hour means one batch for an hour and after that next batch should be executed.
Please suggest me how to get this done.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can call one batch after another within the `finish()` method; you can also use the `System.scheduleBatch()` method if you want to wait an hour (or any arbitrary number of minutes) after the last Batchable method finishes. That said, if you need to call one after the other, you probably don't need to wait an hour, you can just start the next process when the previous one finishes.